# Which is false among the given statements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

[image]

From the given matrix, which of the following statements is False?

A. The linear system has infinite many solutions

B. The linear system has no any solution.

C. The linear system has five variables

D. The linear system has three linear equation

E. None

My answer is A. but I am incorrect. Where did I get it wrong? As I know the given matrix doesn't have any solution so letter A must be false. Can someone explain?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions rather than posting images.  Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs.  Use `^` for exponents and `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: This augmented matrix represents a linear system of equations in three variables (say $x,y,z$). The second row literally says $0x+0y+0z=1$, are there any solutions over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: May I ask what is the false statement? I believe A and C are both false.

Comment: In the question, are you sure there is the verb "is" rather than "are"?

Comment: @BernardMassé Unfortunately yes, and that is my concern. I can only pick one of the choices.

Answer (score 0):

The equations don't have five variables as you've already recognized.

The system is also inconsistent, due to there being an equation of the form 0 = b. It's not possible for there to be infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The second line says that you are looking for a vector (x,y,z) such that 0x+0y+0z=1 and this is clearly impossible. if not you can see the span of the coloumn vectors and see that the last coloumn is not into the span but the pratical passages are the same